# update doesn't work with setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Try to update a state of array using map of es6, got some issue.. What's wrong with this code?

```
this.setState({
  drinks: this.state.drinks.map(o => {
    if (o === this.state.newDrink) {
      return this.state.newDrink;
    }
    return o;
  })
});
```

where drinks is an array. My add functionality is fine but not for update, I think something is wrong above?

My demo https://codesandbox.io/s/nk6qo8krvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing your newdrink with the old drink.

For example if you edit `coffee` and make it `coffeef` you compare in the map function `coffee` with `coffeef`. So it wouldn't change anything.

You should safe a reference of the old value so you can compare it with that.

```
state = {
    drinks: ["coffee", "milo", "plain water"],
    modalIsOpen: false,
    newDrink: "",
    oldDrink: "" // <-- added
};

handleOpenModal = (isEdit, existingDrink) =>
    this.setState({
        modalIsOpen: true,
        newDrink: existingDrink,
        oldDrink: existingDrink, // <-- added
        isEdit
    });

this.setState({
    drinks: this.state.drinks.map(o => {
        console.log(o)
        console.log(this.state.newDrink)
        if (o === this.state.oldDrink) { // <-- changed
            return this.state.newDrink;
        }
        return o;
    }),
    modalIsOpen: false,
    newDrink: ""
});
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/5k2y2l341k

**Warning**

Because you compare the drink names. If you have 2 drinks that are the same name it will change both the values when you change one.

**Edit**

Like @Tho Vu pointed out. You could use the index instead of the name to compare. That's a way better solution and it fixes the above problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/w76978l6mw

Comment: how to fix the warning you said? should I use index instead of comparing names?

Comment: @SharonChai simplest way is passing the target index along with newDrink value. You only apply change to the target index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, it may help.

```
const drinks = this.state.drinks
drinks.map((data) => {
  if (data === this.state.newDrink){
    this.setState({drinks: this.state.newDrink})
  } else {
    this.setState({drinks: data})
  }
})
```

Comment: this.state.drinks.map is not a function?

Comment: yes, it is a function. But it is not a correct way to execute the `fetch` call. Kindly, refer to this https://github.com/airbnb/javascript for writing algorithms with better structure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is basically your comparison in the map. 
Try and console log your map function and you can see the array never changes.

The if statement checks if there is any existing values in the list that are equal to the newDrink value, if there is return the newDrink value.

Clearly, your list will never update, as the newDrink value is different than the existing values.

There is a lot of other problems with your code, however I have resolved your issue in your existing snippet: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/10qpxx2nwj

This solution is slightly faster than mapping over the entire list, as now the code parses in the index of the value you want to change and simply updates the value in the list if you are in "edit mode".

Comment: what other problems you've fixed? at least I can learn from there

Comment: That is the only problem I have fixed.